# Firebase getToken() suddenly returns null on single device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app which is utilizing Firebase - I use it to send notifications and fire events.
The app is working without any issue at the moment on about 100 devices. 
Just recently one single device is always getting `null` when I call `getToken()` and app is becoming unuseful.
This is the only app affected and all started out of the blue - it was working just a week ago.
Code logic seems fine as it is working on all other device.
Tried both `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` and `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),null);` without success.
App was reinstalled, device was factory restored.

The problem is that the device is not with me - it is on remote location so I cannot see what is in the logs. According to the user, nothing has changed.

Just standard implementation, working on 100 device:

```
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = null;
        try {
            refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),null);
            Log.d(TAG, "Token: " + refreshedToken);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Token Err: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String refreshedToken) {
        //Do something with Token
    }
}
```

Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: we cant guess what is happening without any code, show us what you have done and we can look at it.

Comment: There isn't much to show, but updated

Comment: Why do you think it is null?

Comment: I recommend creating a function that logs what you want on a Firebase branch. Or use another remote logging option. That's the only way you are going to figure out what's going on.

Comment: If this is happening to a specific device only, then it might be an issue with the device itself (e.g. killing the FCM service)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use like this:

```
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Also check if you have this on Manifest file:

```
  <!-- FIREBASE SERVICES -->

    <service android:name=".services.firebase.AppFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

And this, on your custom Application class, registered on manifest:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

This works fine on my project.

Comment: He said he already tried `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` and that everything was working, can you explain how your answer improves or corrects the problem?